# Keep looping between the last two routes on this simple React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware, connected-react-router

I have a very simple project you can find on:

https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-looping-between-last-2-routes-xhxu1

On file: `/src/store/middlewares.ts` I have the following middlewares:

```
import { Dispatch, Middleware, AnyAction } from "redux";
import { RootState } from "./rootReducer";
import { createStandardAction } from "typesafe-actions";

export const sendMessage = createStandardAction("message/SEND")<string>();

export const locationMiddleware: Middleware<
  {},
  RootState,
  Dispatch<AnyAction>
> = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === "@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE") {
    store.dispatch(sendMessage("BEFORE D-DAY")); // <--- THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ISSUE
    const result = next(action);
    store.dispatch(sendMessage("AFTER D-DAY"));
    return result;
  } else {
    return next(action);
  }
};

export const messageMiddleware: Middleware<
  {},
  RootState,
  Dispatch<AnyAction>
> = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type === "message/SEND") {
    console.log("Message: ", action.payload);
  }
  return next(action);
};
```

As you can see, on every `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` I dispatch two actions with a message which I capture on another middleware: `messageMiddleware` and I do a `console.log` with them. These actions are dispatched before and after the call to: `next(action)`.

The issue I'm facing is with line: `store.dispatch(sendMessage("BEFORE D-DAY"));`.

When that line is enabled you can do the following steps to reproduce the issue:

1. open the app on the root location (aka: `Page 01`)
2. click link: `Page 02`
3. click link: `Page 03`
4. click back button (you will be redirected to: `Page 02`)
5. click back button (you will be redirected to: `Page 03`, instead of `Page 01` `#FAIL#`)

Please, notice that the back button is the one below (not the acutal button of the browser):

[image]

**In the other hand**, if I uncomment the line which I referenced as the issue, then when clicking the back button the behavior is as expected: `-> Page 02 -> Page 01` straight forward.

It seems that this middleware system doesn't like to dispatch an action before the call to: `next(action)`.

Any idea on how to solve this situation in a good way and keep logging the actions before and after the calls to `next(action)`?

**Requirement:** Use middlewares.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This history object lets us manually control history of the browser. Since React Router is made to change what we see based off of the current URL, the history object can gives us fine-grained control of when and where certain pieces of the application are shown.

1- create a history object used [the history package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history):

2- Basic usage looks like this:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

// Get the current location.
const location = history.location;

// Listen for changes to the current location.
const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
// location is an object like window.location
console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state);
});

// Use push, replace, and go to navigate around.
 history.push('/home', { some: 'state' });

// To stop listening, call the function returned from listen().
unlisten();
```

for more information [enter link description here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/3f69f9e07b0a739419704cffc3b3563133281548/docs/GettingStarted.md)

Comment: I was thinking on using `dispatch / middleware` instead of a listener. Thanks, though.